# Mac os x 10.9.4 run geoserver binary in background

Tags: geoserver, osx

I have had problems running Geoserver 2.5.2 as a WAR package in Tomcat 7 on OS X 10.9. Tomcat runs but when I add Geoserver, Tomcat crashes. This happened after the OS X 10.9.4 update. Well, I didn't bother to use more time to fix this since the Geoserver OS-independant binary seems to work fine.

Only problem I have now is how to have Geoserver run in the background and upon startup. I am used to run programs in the background like this:

**/usr/local/geoserver/bin/startup.sh &**

This starts geoserver but when I close the terminal window, geoserver stops. This may be a stupid question but I would be glad for any help. Also for a startup script.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing and running Vagrant, and then run this inside a ubuntu box. The overall install is still a little tricky, but you wont have any of the crashes or conflicts it sounds like you're having. Plus, you could then install postgresql instead of mysql.

Comment: I am running OS X and have to do that. I also am running PostgreSQL of course since I am running Geoserver. Running ubuntu is no option.The question was related to running the OS-independant Geoserver binary in the background which would be probably the same for any nix OS.